# How can I extract and merge corresponding row variables for designated column in data frame if the row has string variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have this data frame in R of which I'd like to bar plot the terms of one column via `info <- table(df$ForPlot)` . But first I need to merge corresponding row variables with that column IF the that row of the column I'd like to plot has a text (of which some rows have 2 terms some have 1 and others have none). So for example from this:

```
ID    Name     ForPlot
1     cool    
2     nice     ready soft
3     fast      
4     slow     party 
5     good     low
6     bad      
7     true     yo fit
8     false
```

I need a function or a practical way of accomplishing this:

```
ID    Name    ForPlot
1     cool    
2     nice    nice ready soft
3     fast      
4     slow    slow party 
5     good    good low
6     bad      
7     true    true yo fit
8     false
```

So ONLY if my "ForPlot" column has a string, the corresponding row from the "Name" column should be extracted an merged. Any ideas?

**UPDATE** So I thought I new how to plot the frequencies via info <- table(df$ForPlot) which I thought would have taken the frequencies of all the different texts in ForPlot, then run a bar plot of that. I was wrong. Instead it took the entire string of each row (multiple words) as a frequency count. Any ideas on how to make a bar plot from a column with multiple values?

Comment: I updated the post, check if that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `ifelse`

```
df$ForPlot <- ifelse(df$ForPlot != "", paste(df$Name, df$ForPlot), " ")

> df
#Name         ForPlot
#1  Cool                
#2  nice nice ready soft
#3  fast                
#4  slow      slow party
#5  good        good low
#6   bad                
#7  true     true yo fit
#8 false
```

EDIT : Updated the answer as per @Robert Dove's comment

Comment: Thanks but note that `df$ForPlot <- ifelse(df$ForPlot != "", paste(df$Name, df$ForPlot), "")` concatenates the words from `Name` to the first word in every row of `ForPlot` with a word. Instead  `df$ForPlot <- ifelse(df$ForPlot != "", paste(df$Name, df$ForPlot), " ")` prevents the words from concatenating.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
i <- df$ForPlot != ''
df$ForPlot[i] <- paste(df$Name[i], df$ForPlot[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1')`, using the logical condition (`ForPlot!=''`) in 'i', we assign the 'ForPlot' by `paste`ing 'Name' and 'ForPlot' columns.  This should be very fast as we are assigning in place.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[ForPlot!='', ForPlot:= paste(Name, ForPlot)]  
df1
#   ID  Name         ForPlot
#1:  1  cool                
#2:  2  nice nice ready soft
#3:  3  fast                
#4:  4  slow      slow party
#5:  5  good        good low
#6:  6   bad                
#7:  7  true     true yo fit
#8:  8 false
```

#### Update

If we need a bar plot of the word frequency after the transformation, we can `split` the 'ForPlot' column by space (`strsplit`), `unlist` the output `list`, use `table` to get the frequency and then plot with `barplot`.

```
 barplot(table(unlist(strsplit(df1$ForPlot, ' '))))
```

Comment: How would you change the dimensions if the frequency count is low by setting a scale limit of 200 for the frequency count?

Comment: @RobertDove Try `tbl <- table(unlist(strsplit(df1$ForPlot, ' '))); barplot(tbl[tbl>200])`

Comment: Your Update answer worked but your reply answer produced a grey block with no text.

Comment: @RobertDove Can you try with `strsplit(as.character(df1$ForPlot), ' ')`